# Does Mono support SqlDbType Structured?

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, mono, user-defined-types

Is it possible to call a MS SQL Server Stored Procedure with a parameter of type "User-Defined Table"?
I want to run a .NET app on Docker, but I'm stuck with this exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No mapping exists from SqlDbType Structured to a known DbType.
```

Is there any roadmap about Mono development that talks about support to Structured SqlDbType in the near future?

Comment: If you develop any kind of serious project - never use mono with sql server. Mono sql server provider is _full_ of bugs and missing features, and those bugs are not getting fixed for years. This is one of them but you will meet more (and much harder to recognize) later. If you can - switch to .net core. Otherwise - use mono but with posgresql. Otherwise you are in trouble.

Comment: .NET core is arguably in much worse shape than mono in many more regards than just sql server

Comment: @Jeff I personally use second option (mono + postgre), so I indeed should not recommend things I do not use myself (.net core). Is it too buggy or by worse you mean mostly limited functionality?

Comment: Too buggy, unstable

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I cannot switch DBMS, so I must rely on MS SQL Server. I also must use the SqlDbType Structured to invoke my Stored Procedures. Any suggestion on how to invoke them from a Dockerized container (running on Linux, not Windows container)?